# Writing text file with new file extension

Tags: c

I'm trying to ask the user to type the input file they want me to read, and I would like to save one input into two variables where the input file would be "file.txt", but I want the output file to be "file.txt.cvt"

At the moment I'm having problems with it.

Here is what I have

```
printf("Enter file name: "); //asks for filename from user
    scanf("%s %s.cvt", input_file, output_file);      //stores string as "filename"

    inputf = fopen(input_file, "r"); /*file open stored string as
                                     read only. 'filename, "r"'*/

    outputf = fopen(output_file, "w");
```

Comment: Just have the user input the source filespec and then use strcpy and strcat to assemble the output filespec with its extra extension bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strcpy(output_file, input_file); // Make a copy of the input file name
strcat(output_file, ".cvt"); // Add the ".cvt" suffix to it
```